# Android QPython pyttsx requiring ctypes

Tags: ctypes, qpython, pyttsx

I have used pyttsx on my desktop but new to using it on an android mobile phone.

I recently downloaded Pyttsx

```
pip install pyttsx
```

I ran a little tester on the QPython console but came across an error I haven't seen before.

```
>>>import pyttsx
>>>engine = pyttsx.init()
```

the last line of error states:

```
ImportError: cannot import name c_wchar_p
```

So I tried to import ctypes

```
>>>>import ctypes
>>>>import pyttsx
>>>>engine = pyttsx.init()
```

But had the same error occur. Any ideas?

Thanks